# Ajustar logo a la izquierda y botones a la derecha

Tags: html5, css3

como puedo ajustar el logo a la izquierda en el header y los botones a la derecha de este.

Actualmente me queda el logo arriba y los botones abajo de este y quisiera que todo me quedara en la misma linea.

Así se ve mi pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<header> 
    <div>
            <div class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo"></div>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicios.html">SERVICIOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="proyectos.html">PROYECTOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
</header> 

<article> <!--Article sirve para mostrar contenido-->                                                                     <!--Apertura del cuerpo de la página todo lo que se ve-->
    <h1>Sistema Integral de Libros</h1>  
    <p>Control de prestamos de inventarios de libros UT</p> 
</article>
```

**Codigo - CSS3**

```
body{
 background: cornflowerblue;
 color: aqua;  
}
h1{
    color: white;
}
footer {
    /*text-align: center;
    border-top: 3.5px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;*/
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%
}

header 
header nav{
    background-color: #0D82D4;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0.4);
}
header nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
header nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
header nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #0D66AB;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu CSS solo debes agregar algunas propiedades mas, te dejo el ejemplo.

```
body {
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: aqua;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}

div {
    float: left;
}

footer {
    /*text-align: center;
       border-top: 3.5px solid blue;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding-top: 0px;*/
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%
}

header header nav {
    background-color: #0D82D4;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0.4);
}

header nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0D66AB;
}
```

Las propiedades que agrege fueron "**display: inline-block**" y "**float:left**" normalmente debes de agregar el **display:inline-block** para cuando necesites que varios elementos seguidos se posicionen en una misma linea mientras haya espacio mientras que el **float:left** debes de utilizarlo en el elemento unico o que se encuentro solo del cual quieres que lo comiencen a rodear varios elementos que ya tengas en tu codigo, lo entenderas cuando lo ejecutes.

Suerte.

Answer (score 2):

te recomiendo que lo hagas con bootstrap, es un código muy sencillo y te servirá para cualquier dispositivo. Te dejo el código.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg menu">
            <a href="/"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler btn-menu" id="btn-menu" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Servicios</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Proyectos</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y en tu CSS

```
.menu
{
    background: #333;
}

.btn-menu
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.nav-link
{
    color: #FFF;
}

.logo
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Obtendrias algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya solo le das tus estilos propios. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: pero el OP no indica que usa Bootstrap, que pasa si no lo puede usar? creo que la respuesta debería enfocarse mas en lo que el tiene de código

Answer (score 2):

Sin bootstrap puedes usar esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minium-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-logo">
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul  class="menu"> 
                <li><a href="">Nosotros</a></li>   
                <li><a href="">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Proyectos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Y en tu CSS

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header
{
    background: #333;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-logo
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.menu
{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;   
}

.menu a
{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Obtendrías algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Uff gracias por tantas respuestas para un mismo problema.
En verdad Bootstrap no lo he usado jamas, de hecho estos son mis primeros pininos. Probe todas las respuestas y en verdad solucionan todas el problema.Use el codigo sin Bootstrap.
@Alexyz Florez